# retrieving saved javascript from browser and converting to php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am saving form data to ***localStorage in a browser***. I have a problem with retrieval, converting it to php.

The ***sample code*** fails to do the conversion.
This is not a duplicate entry asking about the differences between server side and client side, although that is clearly the cause of the problem I have. What I need is for advice on how to overcome the problem, with some sample script that shows me how to get the desired result. My knowledge of ajax is non-existent, and having looked at various tutorials I cannot see how it would fit into the script in place of the last php lines (which are obviously wrong). I use php extensively and rarely have any use for javascript, except on this occasion.

```html
<?php
  $cust_no=$_POST['cust_no'];
  $cust_id=$_POST['cust_id'];
  $cust_name=$_POST['cust_name'];
  $cust_addr=$_POST['cust_addr'];
  $cust_all=$cust_no."|".$cust_id."|".$cust_name."|".$cust_addr;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <form method = "POST" action = "" name="maint_form">
      <input type="text" name="cust_no" size="10" value="<?php print $cust_no;?>">
      <input type="text" name="cust_id" size="10" value="<?php print $cust_id;?>">
      <input type="text" name="cust_name" size="10" value="<?php echo  $cust_name;?>">
      <input type="text" name="cust_addr" size="10" value="<?php print $cust_addr;?>">
      <p><input type="submit" value="Continue"></p>
    </form>
    <script>
      var customer = <?php echo json_encode($cust_all); ?>;
      if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        localStorage.setItem("custall", customer);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("custall");
      } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
      }
    </script>
    <?php
      $all_delim = '<script>document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =  localStorage.getItem("custall");</script>';
      echo "all_delim=".$all_delim;
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: either pass value to serverside and store then fetch from serverside or store in browser and get from browser, or a mix but you cant put values into php without posting them back to php which can retrieve them again, as your output has already been sent.

Comment: Yes, understood. Is it possible then to pass the javascript data to serverside? I know very little about javascript.

Comment: Yeah do an ajax request.

Comment: Any chance of some help with the ajax request? I looked it up and I cannot see how to apply it to my script.